# Necessary and sufficient conditions for entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement, entanglement-entropy

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for two subsystems of a system to be entangled?

For instance, I think that, for a system with subsystems $A$ and $B$ (so that the space of states of the whole system is $\epsilon=\epsilon_A\otimes \epsilon_B$), the subsystems are entangled if and only if $S[\rho_A]=S[\rho_B]\ne 0$, $S$ being the Von Neumann entropy and $\rho_A=\text{Tr}_B (\rho)$ (*i.e.* the partial trace over the subsystem $B$). However, I was unable to find sources to confirm this.

**EDIT:** I am looking for the general case (mixed and pure states) if possible. If there is no easy answer (that is, if for a general mixed (or pure) state there is no necessary and sufficient conditions), then of course an acceptable answer to this is: without further information, there are no necessary and sufficient conditions that one can speak off.

Comment: It would help if you explained and/or sourced your notation for $S$ and $\rho_A$, but I suspect that there can be no condition of the kind you are looking for. "*An entangled system is defined to be one whose quantum state cannot be factored as a product of states of its local constituents; that is to say, they are not individual particles but are an inseparable whole*", see [Quantum Entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Meaning_of_entanglement). "Subsystems" are not actually subsystems in the usual sense (i.e. not tensor factors of the whole space).

Comment: Are you talking of pure or mixed states?  ---  And are you looking for an answer or for sources?

Comment: @Conifold *"Subsystems" are not actually subsystems in the usual sense (i.e. not tensor factors of the whole space).* --- What is that supposed to mean? Of course they are.

Comment: I think colloquially by "subsystem" people usually mean something that can be considered mostly in isolation, perhaps with few interactions, i.e. something close to ["independent subsystem"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantum+mechanics#Subsystems).

Comment: @Conifold Nope, at least not in quantum information.  A "subsystem" is a tensor factor of your Hilbert space, and makes no statement about the *state* of the system.  BTW, you might want to use @[username] in your replies (otherwise I don't get notified).

Comment: By other conventions, "subsystem" is any subspace, not necessarily a factor, or a subalgebra of the algebra of observables. But the OP does not strike me as a quantum information theorist. In any case, entanglement can not be detected by equating some characteristic computed for the two "subsystems".  I do not use @-s to avoid long-winded comment discussions.

Comment: @Conifold Do you have references for that use?  (And certainly, the question is about quantum information, and the answer for the pure state case *is* "yes".)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52221/discussion-between-conifold-and-norbert-schuch).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Both cases: pure and mixed.

Comment: @XicoSim Then you should make your question *very* precise.  (As of now, you haven't even cared about updating that info in the question!!) Otherwise, it is simply too broad to answer. This could easily cover a whole lecture.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You're right! I will: see the EDIT. I didn't know the answer would "worth a lecture" so to speak (there could be an easy answer - apparently there is not).

Comment: @XicoSim It depends a bit: Just listing the results is doable (though even here there are lots of different criteria for mixed states).  Explaining why they work would go quite far...

Comment: @XicoSim Independent of your edit, I think it would be good if you define your notation, explain the setup, etc.. (Use a few formulas!).  And: It is probably better if you edit any clarification INTO the text, rather than writing "EDIT" below.  This does not make the question easier to understand.

Comment: https://quantiki.org/wiki/separability-criteria